# cannot start Apache service in windows 7 safe mode

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, safe-mode

My PC has a problem(blue screen etc) and can operate only in safe mode.The problem is that Apache service will NOT start in safe mode.Is there a workaround to it?
I have tried numerous times but with no results

I am developing a web app and I need Apache working.

Comment: The safe mode is not intended for normal use. You should first resolve the problem of the operating system to be able to run in normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start Apache in safe mode, because networking is disabled in safe mode. Apache does not work very well without networking...

You *might* be able to start it in "safe mode with networking". However, as pabouk's comment points out, safe mode is only meant for emergency trouble shooting, not for regular use. If you work in safe mode, many other things are likely not to work.

So instead of trying to run Apache in safe mode, fix whatever the base problem is, so you can work without it.

Comment: then,I will have to fix the problem,the only issue is that this is not going to happen soon as I must go to the technician cause I did everything I could from my side.